# Insert \rule in \tabularx?

Tags: tables, tabularx, rules

I would like to have lines for handwriting inside a tabularx, so I wrote this:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage[a4paper, total={18cm, 25cm}]{geometry}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage[french]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{pgffor, ifthen}

\newcommand{\notes}[3][\empty]{%
    \foreach \n in {1,...,#2}{%
        \ifthenelse{\equal{#1}{\empty}}
            {\rule{#3}{0.5pt}\\}
            {\rule{#3}{0.5pt}\vspace{#1}\\}
        }
}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{|l|l|}
    \hline
    \textbf{Question} & \textbf{Answer} \\
    \hline
    foo & \notes[10pt]{3}{5cm}\\
    \hline
\end{tabularx}

\end{document}
```

Unfortunately I get this error

```
! Missing \endgroup inserted.
<inserted text>
                \endgroup
l.27 \end{tabularx}
```

Any idea?

Comment: Why do you use `tabularx` if you don't have an `X` type column in there?

Comment: You can not ues `\\ ` inside of table cells in `l` type columns to start a new line. You might want to replace `\\ ` in your `\notes` command with `\newline` and use the command inside of a `p` or similar column type.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe you want to fill out the space with the lines and also to give more room for the questions.

```latex
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage[a4paper, total={18cm, 25cm}]{geometry}

\usepackage{tabularx,xparse}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\NewDocumentCommand{\notes}{O{10pt}m}
 {
  \prg_replicate:nn { #2-1 }
   {
    \raisebox{#1}{\strut}
    \hrulefill\par
   }
    \raisebox{#1}{\strut}
    \hrulefill
 }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\noindent
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{|>{\hsize=0.5\hsize\raggedright}X|>{\hsize=1.5\hsize}X|}
\hline
\textbf{Question} & \textbf{Answer} \\
\hline
\lipsum[1][1] & \notes{3}\\
\hline
\hline
foo & \notes{1}\\
\hline
\end{tabularx}

\end{document}
```

[image]

You can still call `\notes[20pt]{3}` if you want to leave more space between the lines.

Answer (score 3):

As already mentioned in a comment, you can't use `\\` to sart a new line here. I have therefore replaced the `\\` with `\newline` in your definition of `\notes`. I have also slightly changed the order of some commands in order to allow for more space above the first line. Lastly, I have also added an example using `tabular` and placing the `\notes` command in a `p` type column as well as a `tabularx` example with an `X` type column:

[image]

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage[a4paper, total={18cm, 25cm}]{geometry}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage[french]{babel}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{pgffor, ifthen}

\newcommand{\notes}[3][\empty]{%
    \foreach \n in {1,...,#2}{%
        \ifthenelse{\equal{#1}{\empty}}
            {\rule{#3}{0.5pt}\newline}  %<---- replaced \\ with \newline here
            {\hspace{0pt}\newline\rule{#3}{0.5pt}\vspace{#1}} % <---- removed  \\ at the end of the line and placed  \hspace{0pt}\newline in the beginning 
        }
}

\begin{document}
\noindent
\begin{tabular}{|l|p{5.5cm}|}
    \hline
    \textbf{Question} & \textbf{Answer} \\
    \hline
    foo & \notes[10pt]{3}{5cm}\\
    \hline
    foo & \notes[10pt]{1}{5cm}\\
    \hline
\end{tabular}

\noindent
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{|l|X|}
    \hline
    \textbf{Question} & \textbf{Answer} \\
    \hline
    foo & \notes[10pt]{3}{5cm}\\
    \hline
    foo & \notes[10pt]{1}{5cm}\\
    \hline
\end{tabularx}
\end{document}
```